# Attempting to remove items from a list while looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I am very new to python and I have been trying to remove books with ratings that don't equal to zero from this code:

```
def ratings():
    for i in range(3):
        x = shuffle[i]
        print(x)
        user_rating = int(input(""))
        new_ratings.append(user_rating)
        if user_rating != 0:
            books.remove(x)
        global smalldict 
        smalldict = dict(zip(shuffle,new_ratings))

    print("new user's rating: " + str(smalldict))
```

but when I run the code twice I keep getting this error:

```
list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Now, after doing some research I kind of figured out that I should not remove items from a list I am looping over and one solution is to create a copy instead ,however, when I run the function with the copy, no elements get removed. Here is a sample of what I have tried:

```
def ratings():
    for i in range(3):
        books_buff = books[:]
        x = shuffle[i]
        print(x)
        user_rating = int(input(""))

        new_ratings.append(user_rating)
        if user_rating != 0:
            books_buff.remove(x)
        global smalldict 
        smalldict = dict(zip(shuffle,new_ratings))

    print("new user's rating: " + str(smalldict))
```

Comment: check `x in books_buff` then `books_buff.remove(x)` because if item not found error throw so you need to and `if user_rating != 0 and x in books_buff : ` then `books_buff.remove(x)` do it

Comment: (1) why do you shuffle the books? (2) you're removing records from 'books_buff', which is a local variable.

Comment: It's a project and I am shuffling for a different task. How can I use books_buff as a functional copy because I have tried but the output that I received includes elements that should had been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet is good. The reason you are getting this error is that `remove` throws exception if the element you are trying to remove doesn't exist in the list.

Try:

```
if user_rating != 0 and x in books_buff:
    books.remove(x)
```

instead of:

```
if user_rating != 0:
    books.remove(x)
```

It's true that you shouldn't mutate the list you are iterating over but this is not the case. You are looping over `range(3)` and mutating another iterable (`books`) and it is not a problematic pattern.